# In flutter - how do I best handle and assign predetermined keys to nested lists/arrays in json

Tags: json, list, flutter, object, maps

I'm sending data over ble and have compacted the json strings. The json contains three arrays.

```
{"b":false,"l":261,"a":["0.5","1.8","2.9","1.0"]}
```

I have a model class of Notify. I need to create a model class for "a" that assigns a predefined key to each of the values in the list but I am not sure of the best way. The values always come in a specific order.

```
class Notify{
  bool b;
  int l;
  List<String> a;

  Notify({this.b, this.a, this.d, this.p});

  Notify.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  b = json['b'];
  l = json['l'];
  a = json['a'].cast<String>();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['b'] = this.b;
    data['l'] = this.l;
    data['a'] = this.a;
    return data;
  }
}
```

I get lost in the steps. In this class I think I need to:

1. Turn the "a" array into a list.
2. Convert the Strings to doubles.
3. Convert to a Map providing a key of a0, a1, a2, a3 to the four items in the "a" list.
4. Add four more items to the overall class/map based on a0-a3. Example: a4 = a0 * -1, a5 = a1 * -1, a6 = a2 * -1, a7 = a3.
5. Make it available and usable to the Notify class.

```
    class A {
      double a0;
      double a1;
      double a2;
      double a3;
      double a4;
      double a5;
      double a6;
      double a7;
    
      A a;
    
      A({this.a0, this.a1, this.a2, this.a3, this.a4, this.a5, this.a6, this.a7});
    
      A.fromJson(List<double> json){
// Do bring it in as a list?
        List<double> angleValuesList = List<double>.from(json);
        List<String> angleKeysList = ['a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3'];
        Map<String, double> angleMap = Map.fromIterables(angleKeysList, angleValuesList);
// Then I map the first four values to a0-a3
        //now lost..... how do I get close to items 3-5?
        }
      }
```

I'm hoping my map looks like this so I can create an object from it and drop it in a stream. I receive this packet every 16 milliseconds:

```
{"b":false,"l":261,"a":["a0": "0.5", "a1":"1.8", "a2":"2.9", "a3":"1.0", "a4": "-0.5", "a5":"-1.8", "a6":"-2.9", "a7":"-1.0"]}
```

Thanks for taking the time to read through this!

Comment: maps should use `{}` and list should use `[]`, list is another name for an array, your question is not clear, i guess the question is about parsing json into datatypes!! right

Comment: @neuromancer Sorry about the confusion. I'm confused. Your answer is helping. The question is about parsing json, especially the 'a' list. Once it is parsed into the list I'd like to map it to some key values and add some more key value pairs to the map based on the those four items in the a list. 1) map those four list values to a0, a1, a2, a3 (in that order) then add four more items (key / value) to that map based on those initial four values. ("a4" = a0 * -1), ("a5" = a1 * -1), ("a6" = a2 * -1), ("a7" = a3 * -1).  Then pass them to a class to create the object. Example final json/map above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you parse this `{"b":false,"l":261,"a":["0.5","1.8","2.9","1.0"]}` using `json.decode(data)` like this you will end up having this

```
data = {"b":false,"l":261,"a":["0.5","1.8","2.9","1.0"]}
```

steps

```
Map<String,dynamic> map = json.decode(data);
//as you know the data you have provided
bool b = map['b'] as bool;
int l = map['l'] as int;
//as the list is of type string ["2.2","3.1"]
List<String> a = List.castFrom(map['a']);//or map['a'] as Map<String>
//if the list could have been of type double [2.2,3.1,4.2]
List<double> a = List.castFrom(map['a']);//or map['a'] as Map<double>
```